# Netlogo: How to count ticks from a certain point of initiation

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to build a virus simulator, and I want to make my turtles immune after a certain amount of ticks of being sick. However, I have no idea how to count ticks after I've infected them. I'd like for them to be sick for x ticks, and then be healthy again (and not be able to get infected for a second time). Is there any way to count the ticks after I've infected them, or is there another solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply save the "date" of infection for each turtle, e.g. `set infection-date ticks`.
If then the time since the infection (`ticks - infection-date`) if bigger than x, you can set a variable like `immune?` to true. To avoid infection of immune turtles, simply use `if not immune? [...]`

Here's a minimal running example. Note that `ticks-sick` is uncommented, since I used a slider in the view for setting its value.

```
turtles-own
[
  infected?
  infection-date
  immune?
]

globals
[
;  ticks-sick
]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  
  crt 10
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set infected? False
    set immune? False
    set infection-date "NA"
    show-status
  ]
  
end

to go
  tick
  ask one-of turtles
  [
    get-infected
  ]
  ask turtles
  [
    update-status
    show-status
  ]
end

to get-infected
  if not immune?
  [
    set infected? True
    set infection-date ticks
  ]
end

to update-status
  if not (infection-date = "NA")
  [
    if infected? and (ticks - infection-date) >= ticks-sick
    [
      set infected? False
      set immune? True
    ]
  ]  
end

to show-status
  ifelse infected?
  [ set color red]
  [
    ifelse immune?
    [ set color blue]
    [set color green]
  ]
end
```